# Firefox touch scrolling sometimes stops working

Tags: firefox, windows-8, touchscreen

I'm trying to use Firefox (Nighty-ELM build 20.0a1, and also "normal" 18.0.1) on my touchscreen VAIO Duo 11. I have noticed that the touch-scrolling (slide finger on screen, website follows finger movement) works, but can sometimes stop working. It seems to depend on the web site, e.g. Heise often doesn't work, www.google.com almost never works, whereas Googlemail or Superuser.com work fine all the time.

When the scrolling stops working, the finger just acts like a mouse would, marking text as I swipe by.

Is there any way I can investigate this issue more?

Comment: you're using a **nightly** which is not a stable version. If you think this is a bug, submit it to the bugtracker of Firefox.

Comment: Also happens with the standard release build, so I've updated the question.